# (C#) MongoDB Aggregation Framework: Unwind and project child object of a List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

In my ThingLocations database (MongoDB) I have documents that contain a Notification object. This object contains an Lrrs object, which in turn contains LrrList, a List of Lrr objects.

In short: ThingLocation document -> LastRawThingNotification -> Lrrs -> LrrList.

These Lrr objects have an Lrrid. I want to collect all of these Lrr objects inside each document (unwind), and then count how many times each Lrrid is present in the whole collection.

I wrote the following query that does what I want:

```
db.getCollection('ThingLocations').aggregate([

{$unwind : "$LastRawThingNotification.Lrrs.LrrList"},

{$project : {
    Lrrid : "$LastRawThingNotification.Lrrs.LrrList.Lrrid"
}},

{$group: {
    _id: '$Lrrid',
    ConnectedThingsCount: { $sum: 1 }
}}

])
```

This results in: [(result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZmL9.png)

However, when converting this to C# code for the official client (v2.2.4), I ran into problems. This is my code:

```
var query = await Context.ThingLocations
    .Aggregate()
    .Unwind<ThingLocation, Lrr>(t => t.LastRawThingNotification.Lrrs.LrrList)
    .Project(l => new { Lrrid = l.Lrrid })
    .Group(l => l.Lrrid, g => new { Lrrid = g.Key, ConnectedThingsCount = g.Count() })
    .ToListAsync();
```

But this gives me just one object (instead of 4) with the sum of all Id's. [(result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59ZZi.png) So I assume my Group() statement isn't correct. Thanks in advance for any help!

---

**Edit:**

After debugging and comparing the query the code generates, it appears that the mistake is not in the Group statement, but in the Project. The command should look like this:

```
{$project : {
    Lrrid : "$LastRawThingNotification.Lrrs.LrrList.Lrrid"
}}
```

But this command is generated:

```
{"$project" : {
    "Lrrid" : "$Lrrid",
    "_id" : 0
}}
```

But I wasn't able to fix this. How can I access the child object of the LrrList with the Lambda syntax? (Not an actual child instance, I want to select each "unwound" object)

Comment: Instead of doing ToListAsync(), to a ToString() and compare that with the shell version you are using. That should provide some insight.

Comment: @CraigWilson Thank you, that is a very good method to debug this! The difference is not in the group, but in the Project call. This is what it should be: 
{$project : {
        Lrrid : "$LastRawThingNotification.Lrrs.LrrList.Lrrid"
}}
But this command is generated:
{"$project" : {
      "Lrrid" : "$Lrrid", "_id" : 0
}}

But I do not know how to access the child of the list with the lambda syntax. Any ideas?